# NaN Values inputed into test and train data

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas

I am working on a Data Science project with the Fifa dataset. I cleaned the data and took care of any NaN values in the Data to get it ready to be split into test and train. I need to use StratifiedShuffleSplit in order to split the data. Updated to a cleaner way to divided the value data into groups, but I am still getting NaN values once it goes through the split.

Link to the data set I am using: https://www.kaggle.com/karangadiya/fifa19

```
n = fifa['value'].count()
folds = 3

fifa.sort_values('value', ascending=False, inplace=True)

fifa['group_id'] = np.floor(np.arange(n)/folds)
fifa['value_cat'] = fifa.groupby('group_id', as_index = False)['name'].transform(lambda x: np.random.choice(v_cats, size=x.size, replace = False))
```

At this point when I check the test and train data I now have mystery NaN values inputed. I think the NaN values maybe a result of .loc since I am getting a 'warning' in jupyter.

```
c:\python37\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:6: FutureWarning: 
Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.
```

Code below:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit

split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

for train_index, test_index in split.split(fifa, fifa['value_cat']):
    strat_train_set = fifa.loc[train_index]
    strat_test_set = fifa.loc[test_index]

fifa = strat_train_set.drop('value', axis=1)
value_labels = strat_train_set['value'].copy()
```

PLEASE HELP MY POOR SOUL!!

[image]

Comment: Hi Sam, you can sort the data by value and then randomly sample the rows to do a stratified sample by value. If you post sample data to your question, I'll show you the code to accomplish this.

Comment: posted sample, but posted as an image :/

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 100
folds = 3

# Make some data
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':np.arange(n), 'value':np.random.lognormal(mean=10, sigma=1, size=n)})

# Sort by value
df.sort_values('value', ascending=False, inplace=True)

# Insert 'group' ids, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, ...
df['group_id'] = np.floor(np.arange(n)/folds)

# Randomly assign folds within each group
df['fold'] = df.groupby('group_id', as_index=False)['id'].transform(lambda x: np.random.choice(folds, size=x.size, replace=False))

# Inspect
df.head(10)

    id          value  group_id  fold
46  46  208904.679048       0.0     0
3    3  175730.118616       0.0     2
0    0  137067.103600       0.0     1
87  87  101894.243831       1.0     2
11  11  100570.573379       1.0     1
90  90   93681.391254       1.0     0
73  73   92462.150435       2.0     2
13  13   90349.408620       2.0     1
86  86   87568.402021       2.0     0
88  88   82581.010789       3.0     1
```

Assuming you want k folds, the idea is to sort the data by value, then randomly assign folds 1, 2, ..., k to the first k rows, then do the same to the next k rows, etc.

By the way, you will have more luck getting answers to questions here if you can create reproducible examples with data that make it easy for others to tinker with. :)

Comment: I'm getting a ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index.

Comment: I checked the value counts of the index and the 'value' column and they are equal

Comment: Hey @Ben for the cleaner way to divide up the data, but I am still getting NaNs entered into the test/train data

Comment: @SamRusso what line of code is creating NaNs in your data? Perhaps use this code to downsample your data into a pasteable format that I can work with, so we're at least working against the same dataset. `df.sample(n=20, replace=False).to_dict()`